# How to map unique product colors to 8 basic colors?

Tags: excel, vba, magento, image-processing, magento2

I have an ecommerce store, with lots items that have a few different colors and have about 8 different swatch colors. The only data that have only relation to color is an attribute that has unique color names and the images themselves.

The unique colors are problematic because an example would be Honey, Cream, Violet, or any other synonym for colors, beside this, the only other way to map the colors is the RGB values of the product image colors themselves.

Every product identifier is in rows of a CSV file, Is there any application that helps with this process? Some kind of script that would turn the unique colors into some basic "parent" color? So if it's Violet it would be under Purple or if it's Lime or Forest Green it would be under Green. I would think this is a popular problem for people that use product swatches on ecommerce stores so maybe something exists?

The data is like this:

[image]

The swatch colors are (Black, White, Brown, Orange, Blue, Green, Red, Multi) so the color variations would have to translate to one of those 8. Some of the colors have the word "Red" or "Orange" like "Rust Orange" but some are completely unrelated like "Crimson" which would be under Red, therefore I don't think VBA could work.

Comment: It's a little unclear - could you perhaps post some sample data with a sample of what you're looking to do?  What have you tried so far?  Are you looking for a VBA solution or PHP?

Comment: Well if I we're able to map unique color titles to some basic color category VBA would work but if I need to analyze pixel ratios then PHP would be ideal. I'll try to show how the data is layed out with an edit. Thanks